# phpmyadmin incorrect timestamp for multiple entries

Tags: mysql, http

I have LAMP installed on my server. Server receives a POST request from a node every 5 minutes. Server takes data from POST request and saves it in DB. This process goes very well for some time but suddenly I see that there is incorrect time stamp for some entry and same timestamp is taken up by some further entries and then again correct timestamp starts. Following data shows there- are five columns namely temp,hum,lum,time and timestamp. `time is for saving timestamp received from POST request` and `timestamp is current timestamp` auto saved by PHPmyadmin by configuring default value as current timestamp. This is not one time problem but happening consistently. What could be the issue?

```
temp   hum  light    time                            timestamp

Initially correct timestamp

24.52   59  75       Wed, 15/03/04, 20:40:00         2015-03-04 20:40:48    
24.52   60  76       Wed, 15/03/04, 20:45:00         2015-03-04 20:45:48    
24.52   60  75       Wed, 15/03/04, 20:50:00         2015-03-04 20:50:48    
24.52   60  76       Wed, 15/03/04, 20:55:00         2015-03-04 20:55:48    
23.87   62  75       Wed, 15/03/04, 21:10:00         2015-03-04 21:10:48    
24.19   61  76       Wed, 15/03/04, 21:15:00         2015-03-04 21:15:48    

Incorrect timestamp statrs here

24.19   60  0        Wed, 15/03/04, 21:25:00         2015-03-04 23:33:45    
23.87   60  0        Wed, 15/03/04, 21:30:00         2015-03-04 23:33:45    
24.19   59  0        Wed, 15/03/04, 21:35:00         2015-03-04 23:33:45    
24.19   60  0        Wed, 15/03/04, 21:40:00         2015-03-04 23:33:45    
23.87   61  0        Wed, 15/03/04, 21:45:00         2015-03-04 23:33:45    
23.87   60  0        Wed, 15/03/04, 21:50:00         2015-03-04 23:33:45    
23.87   60  0        Wed, 15/03/04, 22:00:00         2015-03-04 23:33:45    
23.87   60  0        Wed, 15/03/04, 22:05:00         2015-03-04 23:33:45    
23.87   60  0        Wed, 15/03/04, 22:10:00         2015-03-04 23:33:45    
23.87   59  0        Wed, 15/03/04, 22:15:00         2015-03-04 23:33:45    
23.55   60  0        Wed, 15/03/04, 22:25:00         2015-03-04 23:33:45    
23.55   60  0        Wed, 15/03/04, 22:30:00         2015-03-04 23:33:45    
23.55   60  0        Wed, 15/03/04, 22:35:00         2015-03-04 23:33:45    
23.55   60  0        Wed, 15/03/04, 22:45:00         2015-03-04 23:33:45    
23.55   60  0        Wed, 15/03/04, 22:55:00         2015-03-04 23:33:45    
23.55   61  0        Wed, 15/03/04, 23:10:00         2015-03-04 23:33:45    
23.55   60  0        Wed, 15/03/04, 23:15:00         2015-03-04 23:33:45    
23.55   60  0        Wed, 15/03/04, 23:20:00         2015-03-04 23:33:45    
23.23   60  0        Wed, 15/03/04, 23:25:00         2015-03-04 23:33:45    
23.55   60  0        Wed, 15/03/04, 23:30:00         2015-03-04 23:33:45    
23.23   61  0        Wed, 15/03/04, 23:35:00         2015-03-04 23:42:03    
23.23   60  0        Wed, 15/03/04, 23:40:00         2015-03-04 23:42:03    
23.23   60  0        Wed, 15/03/04, 23:45:00         2015-03-05 21:53:46    
23.23   60  0        Wed, 15/03/04, 23:50:00         2015-03-05 21:53:46    
23.55   60  0        Wed, 15/03/04, 23:55:00         2015-03-05 21:53:46    
23.55   60  0        Thu, 15/03/05, 00:00:00         2015-03-05 21:53:46    
23.87   60  0        Thu, 15/03/05, 00:05:00         2015-03-05 21:53:46    
23.87   60  0        Thu, 15/03/05, 00:10:00         2015-03-05 21:53:46    
23.87   60  0        Thu, 15/03/05, 00:15:00         2015-03-05 21:53:46    
23.87   60  0        Thu, 15/03/05, 00:20:00         2015-03-05 21:53:46    
25.16   59  3        Thu, 15/03/05, 07:30:00         2015-03-05 21:53:46    
25.16   59  5        Thu, 15/03/05, 07:40:00         2015-03-05 21:53:46    
25.16   59  5        Thu, 15/03/05, 07:45:00         2015-03-05 21:53:46    
25.16   59  6        Thu, 15/03/05, 07:50:00         2015-03-05 21:53:46    
25.16   59  7        Thu, 15/03/05, 07:55:00         2015-03-05 21:53:46    
25.16   59  8        Thu, 15/03/05, 08:05:00         2015-03-05 21:53:46    
25.16   59  9        Thu, 15/03/05, 08:10:00         2015-03-05 21:53:47    
25.16   59  9        Thu, 15/03/05, 08:15:00         2015-03-05 21:53:47    

correct timestamp starts here
25.16   59  10       Thu, 15/03/05, 08:20:00         2015-03-05 08:20:48    
25.16   59  10       Thu, 15/03/05, 08:25:00         2015-03-05 08:25:48    
25.16   59  75       Thu, 15/03/05, 08:30:00         2015-03-05 08:30:48
```

For image please see here:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyDkK.png

Comment: Are you sure your timestamp column is datetime? I'm wondering why the seconds are almost equal.

Comment: Yes, it is date and time (TimeStamp) type. That is what I'm wondering, because as given in time column every two rows has 5 min delay but in timestamp column it is not. Please note that incorrect timestamp picked is future time not even past or present time.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show the code that inserts the data. Thus we can only speculate. If I understand well, the first column is the time when the Ajax request is sent on the client, and the timestamp is the time when you insert the data.

There are two possibilities :

- the timestamp is updated afterwards by an obscure process somewhere in the code.
- the data doesn't get inserted right away, but is buffered somewhere before it is inserted. The table could be locked by an other process and the mysql server waits until the lock releases. Though in a default configuration this would lead to timeouts somewhere. The delay you observe is noteworthy.

I suppose your timestamp column is defined in mysql as `timestamp default current_timestamp`, and that you do not insert any value. If it isn't, it opens the the possibility for other error sources, like the data is tempered with before it gets saved.

Comment: Hi Lorenz, Initially I suspected the same and delay of 48 seconds is acceptable but for incorrect timestamp part delay is of hours and multiple rows with same timestamp doesn't sound correct and again after some time timestamp is again correct with delay of 48 secs. Please observe last five entries.